# Counting nodes in a binary search tree

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree, nodes

I wrote the following recursive function to count the total nodes in a binary search tree.

```
class BST {
...........
int lc=0,rc=0;
int totalnodes(Node root){
    if(root==null)return 0;
    lc=totalnodes(root.left);
    rc=totalnodes(root.right);
    return rc+lc+1;
  }
}
```

The above function results in a wrong answer.However,the following code works:

```
    class BST {
    int totalnodes(Node root){
        if(root==null)return 0;     
        return totalnodes(root.left)+totalnodes(root.right)+1;
    }
   }
```

What is it that I am missing with the first function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the fact that your `lc` and `rc` are not local. And thus after `lc` was computed for node `root`, it will be overwritten by the call to `totalnodes(root.left)`, while result computation for `root` will take place later.

Try moving your `lc`, `rc` declarations to the method:

```
int totalnodes(Node root){
    if(root==null)return 0;
    int lc=totalnodes(root.left);
    int rc=totalnodes(root.right);
    return rc+lc+1;
}
```